# Deleting duplicate rows on MySQL (leaving at least one)

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, delete-row

I have this table in MySQL:

- id_word
- lang_original (the language from the original word) **VARCHAR(2)**
- lang_target (the language from the translated word) **VARCHAR(2)**
- word (the word itself) **VARCHAR(50)**
- translation (the translation) **VARCHAR(50)**

They should not have duplicates. Is it possible to have a sql query that finds duplicates and deletes them (leaving the first match undeleted)?

**Update** a duplicate would be something that has the same lang_original,lang_target and word (only those 3 fields).

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL - How can I remove duplicate rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/sql-how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows) and many, many others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simpler to create a new table. Previous answers are good, but I like it this way:
Create a new table with a unique key for "lang_original, lang_target, word"

```
CREATE TABLE new_table_can_be_renamed_later ( 
  ..your-fields...
  UNIQUE unique (lang_original,lang_target,workd)
);
```

Then fill your new table with by selecting the old table and use **IGNORE** in your INSERT

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO new_table_can_be_renamed_later 
  SELECT * FROM original_table
```

Please consider Mysql docs for right syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Could work like this:

```
DELETE FROM tbl
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM   tbl t
   WHERE (t.lang_original,   t.lang_target,   t.word)
       = (tbl.lang_original, tbl.lang_target, tbl.word)
   AND tbl.id_word > t.id_word
   )
```

If @Jason is right, and MySQL does not allow to reference the delete table, here is another form that works independently:

```
DELETE FROM tbl
USING (
   SELECT min(id_word) AS min_id, lang_original, lang_target, word
   FROM   tbl t
   GROUP  BY lang_original, lang_target, word
   HAVING count(*) > 1
   ) x
WHERE (tbl.lang_original, tbl.lang_target, tbl.word)
   =  (  x.lang_original,   x.lang_target,   x.word)
AND    tbl.id_word > x.min_id
```

Both variants leave the duplicate with the smallest id alive and kill the rest.

*If* you want to save all your translations to the word with the smallest id in a group of dupes first:

```
UPDATE tbl SET translation = all_trans
FROM  (
   SELECT min(id_word) AS min_id, group_concat(translation) AS all_trans
   FROM   tbl
   GROUP  BY lang_original, lang_target, word
   HAVING count(*) > 1
   ) t
WHERE  tbl.id_word = t.min_id
```

Comment: Please define "duplicate" and tell us about the primary key of the table.

Comment: Does this fall victim to the *can't reference the update table* constraint?

Comment: @JasonMcCreary: Not sure. You mention "update", but it's a delete. Anyway, thanks for the hint. I provided an alternative version, just in case.

Comment: sorry, actually a duplicate would be something that has the same lang,target and word (only those 3 fields).

Comment: Which of the dupes would you want to keep? The one with the smallest id? The one with the longest word in `translation`? Or write a comma-separated list of all translations to the word with the smallest id first?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can do that. 
You are probably better off doing something like

```
select distinct * into yournewtable from originaltable
```

That may work.

Comment: it would be to heavy, there are hundreds of thousands of words.